# Upper bound of $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos((2\pi j)/n + 2\pi\theta)^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, upper-lower-bounds

I am interested in finding a closed form/upper bound on

$$
\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos^2\left(\frac{2\pi j}n + 2\pi\theta\right)
$$
Where $\theta\in[0,1]$. As part of my problem I am taking the supremum over the choice of $\theta$, so if this simplifies things it is fine. Clearly there is a trivial bound of $\leq n$. I am mostly interested if there is some asymptotic improvement to this bound, e.g. if it can be shown to be $o(n)$, though improved constants are of course not bad.

Comment: You mean $\cos((2\pi j)/n + 2\pi\theta)^2=\cos^2((2\pi j)/n + 2\pi\theta)$?

Comment: Yes, the square of $\cos(x)$ for $x$ the expression given.

Comment: I edited the formatting of the expression in the question; feel free to rollback or make changes if I got something wrong

Comment: WA returns a closed form of precisely $\frac{n}{2}$... looks like you could exploit symmetry somehow by matching up the cosines on either end($j=0$ and $n-1$, $j=1$ and $n-2$, etc.) and using some trig identities. If I have time I'll try to find a proof later.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note
\begin{eqnarray}
&&\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos^2((2\pi j)/n + 2\pi\theta)\\
&=&\frac12\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\bigg[1+\cos\bigg(\frac{4\pi j}n + 2\pi\theta\bigg)\bigg]\\
&=&\frac n2+\frac12\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\bigg[\cos\bigg(\frac{4\pi j}n\bigg)\cos(2\pi\theta)-\sin\bigg(\frac{4\pi j}n\bigg)\sin(2\pi\theta)\bigg]\\
&=&\frac n2+\frac12\cos(2\pi\theta)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos\bigg(\frac{4\pi j}n\bigg)-\frac12\sin(2\pi\theta)\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\sin\bigg(\frac{4\pi j}n\bigg).
\end{eqnarray}
Using
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n\cos(jx)=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{1}{2} (n+1) x\right) \cos \left(\frac{n x}{2}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}$$
and
$$ \sum_{j=0}^n\sin(x)=\frac{\sin \left(\frac{nx}{2}\right) \sin \left(\frac{1}{2} (n+1)x\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) }$$
one has
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos\bigg(\frac{4\pi j}n\bigg)=0, \quad\sum_{j=0}^n\sin\bigg(\frac{4\pi j}n\bigg)=0. $$
So
$$ \sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos^2((2\pi j)/n + 2\pi\theta)=\frac n2 $$
and hence
$$ \sup_{\theta\in[0,1]}\sum_{j=0}^n\cos^2((2\pi j)/n + 2\pi\theta)=\frac {n}2. $$

Answer (score 6):

$$\begin{align}
L&:=\frac{n}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\cos\left(\frac{4\pi}{n}j+4\pi\theta  \right)\\
&=\frac{n}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{Re}\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\exp\left(\mathbf{i}\frac{4\pi}{n}j+\mathbf{i}4\pi\theta  \right)  \right)\\
&=\frac{n}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{Re}\left(\exp(\mathbf{i}4\pi\theta)\cdot\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\exp\left(\mathbf{i}\frac{4\pi}{n}j  \right)  \right)\\
&=\frac{n}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{Re}\left(\exp(\mathbf{i}4\pi\theta)\cdot\frac{\exp\left(\mathbf{i}4\pi  \right) - 1}{\exp\left(\mathbf{i}\frac{4\pi}{n}  \right) - 1}\right)\\
&=\frac{n}{2} +\frac{1}{2}\mathcal{Re}\left(\exp(\mathbf{i}4\pi\theta)\cdot\frac{1 - 1}{\exp\left(\mathbf{i}\frac{4\pi}{n}  \right) - 1}\right)\\
&=\frac{n}{2}
\end{align}$$